# Cannot add tailwind to react + typscript + sass + vite stack

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, tailwind-css, vite

i currently have a react + ts app , i have my styles folder inside assets folder that is in src
src/assets/styles/global.scss

the app is built with vite

I have tried all sorts of configurations and fixes to this problem that i have seen online, such as adding lines in context in tailwind.config file , requiring the files in postcss.config,
i tried installing following the tailwind docs for both cli and postCSS

yet all i am getting are "Unknown At rules" in scss files and in css files

Please help me to fix this issue it will be very much appriciated =]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use @apply directive of tailwind in any .scss file instead of only using it main tailwind file(in React)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65532964/how-to-use-apply-directive-of-tailwind-in-any-scss-file-instead-of-only-using)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly set up Vite, Express, Tailwind web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75216812/how-to-properly-set-up-vite-express-tailwind-web-app)

Answer (score 0):

you can't use the tailwind at-rules straight from your sass files. what you need to do instead is:

```scss
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

If that does not solve your issue please share the tailwind config file with us or post a empty project that has the same stack in stackblitz that will be easier to look into it.

Answer (score 0):

**1. Import they files of tailwind**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**2. Add your custom sass or css file**

```
@import "tailwindcss/base";
@import "./app.scss";
@import "tailwindcss/components";
@import "tailwindcss/utilities";
```

**3. Execute the command to compile your files (input CSS or sass):**

```
npx tailwindcss -i ./src/assets/scss/index.scss -o ./src/assets/css/index.css --watch
```

**4. Import the output file:**

```
import './assets/css/index.css'
```

**5. You can use tailwind**

```
const Home = (props: Props) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="text-red-700">test</div>
      <div className="test">test</div>
    </div>
  )
}
```